# zend framework own functions and classes

Tags: zend-framework

Now I have some experience in using the Zend Framework. I want to go deeper in the topic and rewrite some old php projects.

What is the best place to save own functions and classes?
And how do I tell Zend where they are? Or is there already a folder for own stuff? May I have different folders for different files?

For example I want to save a php document with the name math_b.php which includes several special functions to calculate and another one date_b.php which has abilities for datetime stuff. Is that possible or shall I have different files for every function?

I would also like to reuse the functions in other projects and then just copy the folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single "right" answer for this. However, there are several general guidelines/principles that I commonly employ.

### Do not pollute global scope

Namespace your code and keep all functions is classes. So, rather than:

```
function myFunction($x) {
    // do stuff with $x and return a value
}
```

I would have:

```
namespace MyVendorName\SomeComponent;

class SomeUtils
{
    public static function myFunction($x)
    {
         // do stuff with $x and return a value
    }

}
```

Usage is then:

```
use MyVendorName\SomeComponent\SomeUtils;

$val = SomeUtils::myFunction($x);
```

Why bother with all this? Without this kind of namespacing, as you bring more code into your projects from other sources - and as you share/publish your code for others to consume in their projects - you will eventually encounter name conflicts between their functions/variables and yours. Good fences make good neighbors.

### Use an autoloader

The old days of having tons of:

```
require '/path/to/class.php';
```

in your consumer code are long gone. A better approach is to tell PHP - typically during some bootstrap process - where to find the class `MyVendor\MyComponent\MyClass`. This process is called autoloading.

Most code these days conforms to the [PSR-0/PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/) standard that maps name-spaced classnames to file-paths relative to a file root.

In ZF1, one typically adds the `./library` folder to the PHP `include_path` in `./public/index.php` and then add your vendor namespace into the `autoloaderNameSpaces` array in `./application/config.ini`:

```
autoloaderNameSpaces[] = 'MyVendor';
```

and places a class like `MyVendor\MyComponent\MyClass` in the file:

```
./library/MyVendor/MyComponent/MyClass.php
```

You can then reference a class of the form `MyVendor\MyComponent\MyClass` simply with:

```
// At top of consuming file
use MyVendor\MyComponent\MyClass;

// In the consuming page/script/class.
$instance = new MyClass(); // instantiation
$val = MyClass::myStaticMethod(); // static method call
```

### Determine the scope of usage

If I have functionality is required only for a particular class, then I keep that function as a method (or a collection of methods) in the class in which it is used.

If I have some functionality that will be consumed in multiple places in a single project, then I might break it out into a single class in my own library namespace, perhaps `MyVendor`.

If I think that a function/class will be consumed by multiple projects, then I break it out into its own project with its own repo (on Github, for example), make it accessible via [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/), optimally registering it with [Packagist](https://packagist.org/), and pay close attention to [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/) so that consumers of my package receive a stable and predictable product.

Copying folders from one project into another is do-able, of course, but it often runs into problems as you fix bugs, add functionality, and (sometimes) break backward-compatibility. That's why it is usually preferable to have those functions/classes in a separate, semantically-versioned project that serves as a single source-of-truth for that code.

### Conclusion

Breaking functionality out into separate, namespaced classes that are autoloaded in a standard way gives plenty of "space" in which to develop custom functionality that is more easily consumed, more easily re-used, and more easily tested (a large topic for another time).